# How to merge my code with code of the driver?

Tags: c, linux, arduino, driver, kernel-module

So, what I have:

1)I have a source code of driver for ch34x usb-to-serial adaptor which installed on my arduino. [Here is it.](http://pastebin.com/dtx9T4sL)

2)I have my code, which reads data from /dev/ttyUSBx (x - some number) and prints it to the terminal. [Here is it.](http://pastebin.com/RxtMWTQJ)

3)I can write a blank module, which can be compiled and registered in system.

What I need:

I need to write a kernel module which can be a driver for my arduino(I have paragrpaph 1 for it. When I compile this driver, it works fine, creates device in `/dev/` and I can `read()` from this device). And also this module should read data from the device and send it, for example, to the file or to the terminal(place where it will be sent not really important).

So, the question is - how can I merge the driver(1) and my code(2) to get a working module which will do things above? I tried to do it many ways, but looks like I always do something wrong.

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: why  not write user-space char device, see https://lwn.net/Articles/308445/ ?

Comment: Hello, @user1034749, as I understand, the driver (paragraph 1) already doing a thing like that. I just need to merge driver code and code of my reading function to make all this functionality to be in one module. Or I don't understand something...(most likely :) )